# How to get the application id in Android?

Tags: android

I need to uniquely identify Android app installed on any Android device. I know that every Android device has unique id and every application is like a Linux user for Android.

But there are cases when two applications can have same userID if they are signed with the same key and are designed to share content.

Is there any way to identify unique id for every application on every android device ? I want to broadcast something based on this unique id and then the application should receive that and act accordingly.

Can we also get the application id / user id via code ?

Thanks in advance !!

Cheers,
Prateek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that package name is unique for every application

Comment: @Prateek Jain that is not a correct statement it is not possible to install a second apk with the same package name.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we can get application id of each application installed on device by using the following code. And if you are signing by the same key also, application package name will be different.

```
ResolveInfo info = mApps.get(position);
```

- `info.activityInfo.packageName` will return the unique package name. `mApps` is of type `List<ResolveInfo> mApps`.
- `.get(position)` will return the item's position in the list view or grid view.

Thanks,
Md Saifuddin

Answer (score 1):

The PackageInfo.sharedUserId field will show the user Id assigned in the manifest.

If you want two applications to have the same userId, so they can see each other's data and run in the same process, then assign them the same userId in the manifest:

android:sharedUserId="app1"
The two packages with the same sharedUserId need to have the same signature too.

Comment: I don't want to share the user id in two different applications. What I want to know is - Is there any way to uniquely identify the applications even if they share a "sharedUserId"?

Comment: Or get that application/user Id via Code?